# How to use breakpoints in F# files in C#/F# MVC4?

Tags: f#, breakpoints

I am in the middle of a rather large project that uses the `C#-F# MVC4 template`.  The template breaks up the solution into two projects: `[ProjectName]Web` and `[ProjectName]WebApp`.  All of the F# code resides in the latter.

I cannot debug the solution unless I hit `F5` from `Global.asax` in `[ProjectName]Web`.  But this always misses the breakpoints I have set in my F# files in `[ProjectName]WebApp`.

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: Are you in release mode or using inlined functions?

Comment: I am in debug mode (when I am developing).  There are a few inlined functions, but the vast majority are not inlined.  The breakpoints are usually not in inlined functions.

Comment: Are you in an fsx file?

Comment: No, the breakpoints are in `.fs` files.  (Almost all of them have corresponding `.fis` files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to attach to an IIS process. Depending on what you are using this will be listed as either issexpress.exe or w3wp.exe in the debugger attach screen. To do this go to the menu Debug | Attach to process and select the process to attach. Once attached you can debug as per normal without going through F5.

Below is the screenshot of IIS express being listed in the debugger attach screen. Check 'Show processes from all users' if the said processes are not listed.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I think you mean w3wp.exe.

Comment: @ildjarn - indeed. that's what I meant. Thanks for the correction. I have corrected my post.